# Is this a video or a gif

Tags: video, web, html, gif, animated-gif

I'm newbie in web development and I'm trying to find information about the animation found in the background of this webpage (http://civa.com.pe/) in order to use something like that in the page i'll develop. You can see that animation at the back of the page in a soft purple color is just the logo but I don't know if it's a gif image or a video.
Please give me a hand with that.
[The animated part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMb7U.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click in most browsers you will get an option to 'inspect' the element (you may need to enable developer tools in your browser).

When you do this with the pointer over the background in the above site, you can see this is a video from the HTML:

```html
<video autoplay="" preload="" loop="" muted="" class="hidden-xs">
    <source src="http://civa.com.pe/wp-content/themes/civa/assets/img/back-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Comment: That was not the part of the page i was referring to but your suggestion helped me. I've seen the code of the page and finally i've found out that it was SVG animation.